# How to find documents with repeated words in SOLR v.7.5

Tags: select, solr

I have document with the following fields:

- street: 28 Oktovriou
- housenumber: 28

This document was indexed by copyfield.

When I try to find this document, I use the following query:

```
select?q=28*%20AND%20%2228%20Oktovriou%22*
```

But by this query I also get the documents which contain word `28` only one time.

So, how should I make the query to find the documents which contain `28` twice and also `Oktovriou`?

Comment: Is your requirement actually to find those that have the one value twice and the other value once, or the documents that have both values present (in any count)?

Comment: If I put "28 AND 28" in query, I should get the document which contains "28" twice.

Comment: That won't work, unless you prefix both with the fields you want to search (so `street:28 AND housenumber:28`). If you can control the query, you can use `termfreq` to do a function query: `if(gt(termfreq(catch_all_field,'28'), 1), 0, 1)`, which will return 0 or 1 depending on if the number of times 28 occurs is 2 or more.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. But it won't work in case when we have "28 AND 2*" in query.

Comment: Wildcard queries are a history by itself, but no, that won't work. But using actual boolean clauses with the field name prefixed will (if your requirement is a hit in both fields instead). Update your question with the proper examples of queries you want to have answered, your test data and what your wanted output is, instead of me answering and asking in a comment and you introducing a new query you also want answered :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

1. You could use [phrase search with slop/proximity](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/the-standard-query-parser.html#proximity-searches): address:"28 Oktovriou 28"~10
2. For more complex matches, [Complex Phrase Query Parser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/other-parsers.html#complex-phrase-query-parser) may be relevant as well

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!
The first point works, but instead of ~10 I should put ~1000.
But the main question is: user can put not full street name, for example "28 oktov 28" and that is why I use * after each words. But, unfortunately character ~ doesn't work with * , i.e., if I use the following query I won't get the document:
"28* Oktov* 28*"~1000
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Wildcards are not the best approach in Solr, performance wise. You could look into edge NGrams instead. However, the second answer (Complex Phrase) does support wild cards. Try using that.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! As a temporary solution I sort the results of search by (termfreq(field,value) desc. On the next step I'm going to learn different tokenizer as you said.

Comment: Make sure to accept answers and/or vote up useful answers and comments. This helps other people to know what worked.